# ARista 7280SR-48C6 routing table size

Tags: arista

i want to use a 7280SR-48C6 as edge switch and i read arista datasheet but i could not find how many ipv4 and ipv6 it can hold. can i have 4-5x IP transits with full tables and 30-40x private peering ? how many routes it can hold in fib and then install to rib?
Thank you

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this datasheet](https://www.arista.com/assets/data/pdf/Datasheets/7280SRAM_48C6%20datasheet.pdf), at least 768K host routes and 1M LPM routes should be possible.